# Count records of post table by category_type based on max assignments

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a POST table, a CATEGORY table, a CATEGORY_TYPE table and a ASSIGNMENT table, I explain the ASSIGNMENT table contains assignments for each category to an category_type, for example the POST whose ID = 4 with category_id= 3 which had the last assignment in 2018 category_type_id = 1, so the query should bring the last assignment for specific year

```
//POST table
+----+-------------+
| id | category_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |      1      |
|  2 |      2      |
|  3 |      1      |
|  4 |      3      |
|  5 |      1      |
|  6 |      1      |
|  7 |      1      |
|  8 |      3      |
|  9 |      2      |
| 10 |      2      |
| 11 |      4      |
+----+-------------+

//CATEGORY table
+----+------------------+
| id |   category_name  |
+----+------------------+
|  1 |    category_1    |
|  2 |    category_2    |
|  3 |    category_3    |
|  4 |    category_4    |
|  5 |    category_5    |
+----+------------------+

//CATEGORY_TYPE table
+----+------------------+
| id |  category_type   |
+----+------------------+
|  1 |     type_1       |
|  2 |     type_2       |
|  3 |     type_3       |
+----+------------------+

//ASSIGNMENT table
+----+------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| id |   category_id    |   category_type_id  | Date         |
+----+------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 |        1         |          3          |  2017-01-01  |
|  2 |        3         |          2          |  2017-11-10  |
|  3 |        1         |          2          |  2017-12-02  |
|  4 |        5         |          3          |  2018-01-01  |
|  5 |        2         |          1          |  2018-04-03  |
|  6 |        3         |          1          |  2018-05-06  |
|  7 |        2         |          2          |  2018-09-21  |
|  8 |        1         |          3          |  2018-11-01  |
|  9 |        4         |          2          |  2018-12-29  |
| 10 |        3         |          3          |  2019-02-16  |
| 11 |        5         |          1          |  2019-06-20  |
| 12 |        1         |          1          |  2019-12-01  |
+----+------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

So i would like to count post by category_type depending on the last assignment for specifique year

```
select category_type, count(*) as cnt 
from(
select max(ctt.category_type) AS category_type
from post p 
        inner join category ct on (p.category_id = ct.id)
        left outer join (
            select category_id,
            max(category_type_id) keep (dense_rank last order by id) AS category_type_id
            from assignment ag
            where extract (year from ag.date) <= 2018
            group by category_id
            ) ag
        on (ct.id= ag.category_type_id)
        left join category_type ctt on ag.category_type_id = ctt.id      
        group by ctt.id
)
group by category_type;
```

following the logic here is the data expected to be selected

```
+---------------+----------+
| category_type |    cnt   |
+---------------+----------+
|     type_1    |     2    |
|     type_2    |     4    |
|     type_3    |     5    |
+---------------+----------+
```

according data the sum of cnt = 11 posts which is correct
but the problem is that the query dont return the right result

```
+---------------+----------+
| category_type |    cnt   |
+---------------+----------+
|     type_1    |     4    |
|     type_2    |     6    |
|     type_3    |     8    |
+---------------+----------+
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach. You can use a `Correlated Subquery` to return the latest `CATEGORY_TYPE_ID` for the applicable `ASSIGN_DATE` and `CATEGORY_ID`. Below you will see that I select the latest `ASSIGN_DATE` for the `CATEGORY_ID` on/before `2018`.

**SQL**:

```
SELECT
  d.CATEGORY_TYPE,
  COUNT(a.ID) AS POST_CNT
FROM
  POST a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORY b ON a.CATEGORY_ID = b.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      a.ID,
      a.CATEGORY_ID,
      a.CATEGORY_TYPE_ID,
      a.ASSIGN_DATE
    FROM
      ASSIGNMENT a
      /* RETURN LATEST CATEGORY_TYPE_ID FOR CATEGORY_ID FOR THE APPLICABLE YEAR VIA CORRELATED SUBQUERY */
    WHERE
      a.ASSIGN_DATE = (
        SELECT
          MAX(ASSIGN_DATE)
        FROM
          ASSIGNMENT
        WHERE
          CATEGORY_ID = a.CATEGORY_ID
          AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ASSIGN_DATE) <= 2018)
  ) c ON b.ID = c.CATEGORY_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORY_TYPE d ON c.CATEGORY_TYPE_ID = d.ID
GROUP BY
  d.CATEGORY_TYPE
ORDER BY
  d.CATEGORY_TYPE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd723a/19/0)**:

```
| CATEGORY_TYPE | POST_CNT |
|---------------|----------|
|        type_1 |        2 |
|        type_2 |        4 |
|        type_3 |        5 |
```